# How to store the quantity of item for different sizes in the database

Tags: java, mysql, database, e-commerce

I am creating an ecommerce app. I cannot find a way to store quantity of different sizes of the same product. Suppose I have a t shirt which has 3 sizes available xl,xxl,xxxl with quantity 20 , 25 , 30 . Now how can I store this into the MySQL table ?

One way I was thinking to do this as to create a String like xl+20,xxl+25,xxxl+30 and store it into a column and I can break this String at "," and "+" while retrieving it but I don't think it is a good idea .

Is there any other better way to do this ?

Comment: The size has nothing to do with how many of them you have. Therefore, the information should be stored in different fields. Just as an example I would do something like a table `Inventory`with the fields `ProductID`, `Size` and `Quantity`.

Comment: seller can have different quantities availability for different sizes . That's what I wanted to store .

Comment: Design is a trade-off between engineering 'soundness' and convenience. One 'proper' way of doing this would be to have `Product` `Size` and `Product_Size` where products would have a one-to-many relation to size. `Product_Size` would be the intermediary table. That way you wouldn't have informational redundancy

Answer (score 1):

You can break the same product into separate lines for each size, which is scalable in case you want to add or remove things in the future.

```
id(pk), product_id, size , quantity
1, 100, xl, 20
2, 100, xxl, 25
3, 100, xxxl ,30
```